# Proof set closed.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I have some problems to proof that a set is closed.
I have $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ and I know that $\exists \ \alpha$ s.t. the set $A  = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is non-empty, bounded and $A \setminus \partial A$ is open. I want to prove that A is compact, so because I know that is bounded I have only to prove that is closed. Intuitively I get the idea, thanks to the fact that $f$ is continuos, but I can't prove it in a formal way. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: If you fix a convergent sequence $x_n\in A$ then you only need to prove that $f(\lim x_n)\le\alpha$

Comment: Note that "proof" and "prove" are two different words. Also, please use more specific titles.

Comment: $f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha])$ is closed, $f$ is continuos , inverse image of a closed set is closed.

Comment: Thanks you guys! And sorry if i not used specific terms, sorry for that. I have also to proof that there are some minima points of $f$ in the interior of $A$, I have some problems, also here. I wanted to try to construct a compact set in the interior but I don't know If is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

Your set $A=f^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha])$, the interval $(-\infty,\alpha]$ is closed and $f$ is continuous.

Recall that $f$ is continuous iff the pre-image of any open set (closed, respectively) is open (closed, respectively).